# calculate window correction factor

Tags: matlab, window

When using windows on my signal, I want to use a correction factor to correct either the energy or the amplitude for the window.

I have written some other code to calculate both the energy and amplitude factors and ratio. See here:

```
% signal
dt = 0.001;
fs = 1/dt;
x = 0:dt:10;
N = length(x);
y = 3*sin(2*pi*x*52) + 5.2*sin(2*pi*x*53) + 14*randn(size(x));

figure(1)
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(x,y)
title('signal')

rms_y = rms(y);

% window
w = hanning(N);   w = w';

rms_w = rms(w);
mean_w = mean(w);

ECF = 1/rms_w; % Energy correctionfactor
ACF = 1/mean_w; % Amplitude correctionfactor

% windowed signal
ws = (w.*y);

rms_ws = rms(ws); 

% fft signal
Z = 100*N; % add zeros
f = fs*(0:Z/2)/Z;

Yfft = fft(y,Z);
Y2 = abs(Yfft)/N;
Y = Y2(1:Z/2+1);
Y(2:end-1) = 2*Y(2:end-1);

figure(1)
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(f,Y)
title('signal frequency spectrum')
xlim([48 57]);

rms_Y = rms(Y);

% fft windowed signal
Yfftws = fft(ws,Z);
Y6 = abs(Yfftws)/N;
Y6 = ECF*Y6;                 % apply correctionfactor
Y5 = Y6(1:Z/2+1);
Y5(2:end-1) = 2*Y5(2:end-1);

figure(1)
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(f,Y5)
title('windowed frequency spectrum with correction factor')
xlim([48 57]);

rms_Yws = rms(Y5);

amplitude_Y = max(Y);
amplitude_Y_windowed = max(Y5);

ratio_amplitude = amplitude_Y/amplitude_Y_windowed
ratio_energy = rms_Y/rms_Yws
```

If I change ECF to ACF at the **% apply correction factor**, it corrects the amplitude factor. If I change the window to any window, like blackman or flattopwin, the ratio of either the energy or the amplitude is approximately 1, as it should. With the ACF applied, both peaks are approx. the same value for normal FFT plot and windowed FFT plot, as it should.

But, as stated in the table on this site https://community.plm.automation.siemens.com/t5/Testing-Knowledge-Base/Window-Correction-Factors/ta-p/431775 , for the flattopwin ECF = 2.26 and ACF = 4.18. Calculate from my script, the factors for flattopwin are ECF = 2.3891 and ACF = 4.6391, which is not the same as in the table. Same for using blackman: ECF and ACF does not match. Tho, for using hamming and hanning, the values are correct.

Do I calculate both the ECF and ACF right?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is correct. On the site the window name for Blackman is confusingly equated with blackmanharris. Try this and the values should match. And for flattop, check the coefficients. There are many variants and it is likely that on the site a different configuration was used.

The correction factors can also be calculated more simply with:

energy_correction = 1/rms(window)

amplitude_correction = N/sum(window), where N is the signal length (the higher the more accurate is the correction)